# Why could Tetsuo's hand reproduce many flesh, muscles and veins using his ESP?

Tags: akira

In the last minute of the *Akira* movie, we could see that Tetsuo's hand had several injuries, until some laser beam from outer space shot on him, cutting his arm off.

In short, he made an artificial arm using metal and building scrap. Everything looked fine until his ability got out of control. The veins and nerves spread into many material things, and suddenly he could produce flesh, muscles and veins from his cut-off hand using his ESP ability.

[image: Nerves and veins started to spread]

[image: Produce flesh, veins, and muscles]

How could he produce such things? I thought ESP is an ability to move and destroy things that exist using mind control, not to produce a new skin and flesh.

Answer (score 1):

In the manga, it is explained that the power that gives Tetsuo his psychokinetic abilities is trying to break free, as his body is no longer enough to contain it. To compensate for this, his body is trying to absorb material from all around him. As for why he could produce additional matter, the power trying to break free might be partially converting energy into additional mass during his breakdown, allowing him to generate additional flesh.

Comment: If you could added some references with link or other credible sources which support your answer, that woukd be great.

Comment: As mentioned by @Gagantous , provide sources for your answer. Answers, from what others here always say, should require no verification from the user so it should be able to stand on its own. It should also be verified easily if there is doubt from others, hence the need for sources.